# How to draw shape of convex lens in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to draw the shape of convex lens in three.js . Using the EllipseCurve of three.js I can draw a simple verticle ellipse. But I need to draw the shape of a convex lens.Also how to controllers to it so that the user can change the width of the length?

Comment: _Does length have a width?_

Comment: You can set scaling one of dimensions of a mesh with THREE.SphereGeometry(): mesh.scale.set(1, 1, 0.1);. Or you can use [THREE.LatheGeometry()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=lathe#Reference/Geometries/LatheGeometry) to create a solid of revolution.

Comment: I get a convex lens type shape by scaling a sphere.But I need to add handlers to it so that the user can resize it. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using two `SphereBufferGeometry` objects to form the two sides of the convex lens. You will have to adjust the coordinates of both geometries so they touch, which is not shown here.

```
 // Bottom half
 var geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 1, 32, 32,  
      0, Math.PI*2, 0, 0.5);
 // Top half
 var geometry2 = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 1, 32, 32,  
      0, Math.PI*2, Math.PI*2 - 0.5, 0.5);
```